# Jmeter jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector : Analysing issue

Tags: perfmon

I am unable to understand the result of the performance metrics generated in Jmeter. Can anyone please help me undersand this results. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjntA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Every Performance Metrics uses different scale. For Example Memory utilization can be calculated with % usage as well as in Mbs.
I would suggest you look each utilization individual for better understanding.

To do that, you can select Rows -> Check only one (for example memory) -> then see the graph of it coming back to the Chart again.
Also in settings option you can edit 'force maximum Y axis value', For ex- 100 (To calculate in percentage).

Same can be applied for other matrices.

Like if you agree.
Thanks

Comment: I selected rows but nothing is getting reflected on the Chart. Can you please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add perfmon listner 2 times in thread group. Select 1 value in each. For example, 1st perfmon you use for CPU and 2nd use for Memory capture. Then run your test and understand the difference.